# STM32 not booting without J-link

Tags: embedded, stm32, bootloader, reset, stm32f4

I've got a device with STM32F439 microcontroller on it. I flashed the firmware using the J-Flash utitilty (flashed and read back data is same). Then started the application from J-flash: everyting works fine. But when I restart the application without connected J-link the device is not booting.

P.S.: I think it should work if I would perform hardware reset, but device should start automatically on power on.

Update #1: I found a test board with STM32F417 on it and repeated the same action. The same result. Not starting without connected J-Link. But when I push "reset" button - it starts immediately. May be I should perform some internal resets before start?

Update #2: controller boots when there is permanent high voltage level on NRST pin.

Comment: Unconnected grounds, perhaps? Seriously, without more details, we are useless.

Comment: Never used one with an STM32 but on some devices a J-Link will power the target by default, it could be as simple as you don't have power to the microcontroller when removed.

Comment: I'm agree with @Dzarda you have to put more details here. two pictures of two situations of your circuits will help too much.

Comment: Microcontroller has power without connected J-Link.

Comment: Check your initialization.  Debuggers often do some initialization independently, which may be missing in the code.

Comment: Debuggers perform reset. The reason: stack pointer and the PC need to be initialized correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution. The problem was in JTAG connector: he gave a low level on NRST pin so external reset occured indefinitely.

Comment: JTAG connector by itself should not pull NRST low, it's just a dangling pin. You need a pull-up on NRST for standalone operations.